# NPOI xls "TEXT" function converting "/" to "-" on evaluate formulas

Tags: c#, excel, xls, npoi

I am using NPOI to input a date into a spreadsheet, then inside the xls I have the formula =TEXT(InputDateNamedRange, "yyyy/MM") to format the date to text for use elsewhere.

The problem is that the "/" in the format string is being replaced with a "-". E.g. 2014/04/25 becomes 2014-04 instead of 2014/04 as I expect.

On my pc it works but when I run on another pc this happens. Surely the machine should play no part in a specific format string?

Comment: Try `=TEXT(InputDateNamedRange, "yyyy/mm")`

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Definitely not, `mm` is the placeholder for minutes.

Comment: @BenVoigt, It is strange to me too, but info from [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the `/` is interpreted as a placeholder for the system date separator.

In Excel (tested with 2013), it works ok, as predicted by [the documentation](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010342952.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP010342953) which says

> If you include any of the following characters in the *format_text* argument, they are displayed exactly as entered.

and then lists the forward slash `/`.

But in other Microsoft products, `/` IS [documented as the date separator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and you can use `\/` to "escape" it, taking away its special meaning, and getting a literal `/` in the output.

Since NPOI is built in .NET, perhaps it's actually using the .NET rules instead of the Excel ones?

Since Excel is perfectly happy with `=TEXT(value, "yyyy\/MM")` I suggest you use that.

Comment: I really thought adding the backslash would do the trick, but no. Still giving me the - instead. So frustrating. The SUBSTITUTE function of excel looks like it can be a work-around.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find an answer to the problem, but I did come up with a work-around: use the "substitute" function of excel to replace the "-" with "/". Good enough for me. (still want to know the reason why the formatter didn't do what was asked of it)